# Kotlin Spring boot Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin

I'm trying to make a Kotlin rest application with Spring boot and Angular 5, when i run de project it works fine until i want to access and specific URL, it shows "Whitelabel Error Page"

Comment: If you are new to Stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question. Also, provide additional details as to what the error is and show us your code.

Comment: Whitelabel error page is default error handling for spring-boot web applications. post your code and exceptions logs if any to guide you on this

Answer (score 0):

Your folders (api, model, repository.. etc) should be in the same package as your `KotlinApplication.kt`.
as an example see this picture below:

[image]

the **@SpringBootApplication** annotation that your `KotlinApplication` class has actually consists of **@ComponentScan** which scans the folder and the it's sub-folders by default.
In your case your application probably can't see the resource file.